# angular directive inverse isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am creating a directive that wraps a component passing down specific attributes. So far I have the following. Note that it needs to have access to the parent scope in order to work properly. The problem is that isOpen variable which then gets placed on the parent scope. So two date pickers in the same scope (eg a start and end date) cannot trigger independently.

```
app.directive('mzDatePicker', [
'underscore',
(_) => {
'use strict'
const dasherize = name =>
  name.replace(/[A-Z]/g, (letter, pos) => (pos ? '-' : '') + letter.toLowerCase());

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: (el, attr) => {
        //Note ng-required won't work with the same strategy as other attributes
        return `
            <input uib-datepicker-popup
                is-open="isOpen"
                show-weeks="false"
                show-button-bar="false"
                ng-required="${'undefined' == typeof attr.ngRequired ? '' : 'true'}" 
                ${
                    _.chain(attr)
                        .pick('ngModel', 'ngModelOptions', 'placeholder', 'class', 'maxDate', 'minDate', 'dateDisabled')
                        .pairs()
                        .map(x => `${dasherize(x[0])}="${x[1]}"`)
                        .value()
                        .join(' ')
                }
                />
            <button type="button" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        `
    }
} }])
```

Can I have the directive isolate *just the isOpen variable in the scope*?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, turns out I want a child scope. setting

```
scope: true
```

works well.